# Linear Regression Library that can take NaN and inf values suggestion

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have data set that has both NaN and inf values and I am looking for linear regression library that can take both NaN and inf values. I have used sklearn in the past but also have seen linregress used a lot, but both libraries require NaN and inf values to be dropped beforehand.

Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: In general, it's _you_ who must deal with these values not a regression library (it would need to know how you want these values to be treated). You can remove them or replace them with the average of its corresponding feature or something else.

Comment: Numerical values are generally required for fitting algorithms.  After all, how would you solve for `x` in e.g.  `x = 4 + np.nan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Moosefeather mentioned you have to deal with this yourself. Easiest option is to drop those samples or replace them with an average.

A more sophisticated approach would be something like estimating the expected missing value conditioned on the other values of the observation. This is more work and if you have enough clean data dropping the bad values might be better.